# Copy from guest Ubuntu terminal in virual machine to Microsoft Word on host windows

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, clipboard

Is it possible to copy from the Ubuntu terminal to Microsoft Word? In fact, Microsoft Word is installed on my computer while I am running Ubuntu on a virtual machine.

Comment: I tried, that did not work :/. Thank you for your response though.

Comment: How have you installed Microsoft Word? It is not installed by default and not available for Ubuntu either.

Comment: Microsoft Word is installed on my the host computer not the VM. Can I still do that?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu in a VM? Do you want to copy the Ubuntu VM's terminal output to the host's MS Word? Please [edit] your question to add this.

Comment: Yeap this is what I want to do. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Are you using Oracle virtual box?

Answer (score 1):

Use your mouse to select the text in the terminal.
Right-click in the terminal and choose 'Copy'.
Then paste the text from the clipboard in Word (Right-click 'Paste').

Does this help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy something from a terminal with your mouse :

- Select the text
- Right-clic > copy
- Right-clic > paste

You can also do it with your keyboard :

- Select the text
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy (ctrl-shift-v to paste something, btw)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to your document (you opened it before)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to past once in your document

You can also use a trick to get the terminal-printed informations in a file :

- simply use `my-commandline-as-usual > /path/to/file.doc`

Answer (score 1):

Though OP did not clearly mentioned I am assuming OP is using `Oracle VM VirtualBox`. To enable copy and paste between host and guest one need to install `guest addition`.

Download [Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and install on host (windows). Next open VM go to guest (Ubuntu) and install guest addition.

To install you need to go to **System Settings >> Additional Dirvers**, and install guest addition. Otherwise take a look on [this tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-guest-addons.html). It shows the other way.

Now you need to enable clipboard sharing. Go to virtual machine.

Go to **Devices >> Shared Clipboard** and check **Bidirectional**

The following snap should make it clear.

[image]

Now you can directly copy from a guest to host or vice-verse. Either right click and copy or use custom copy ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> ) paste ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> ) shortcuts.

For terminal copy ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> ) and paste ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> )

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+C for copy.
Ctrl+C terminates a program, so you need the shift

EDIT:
If its on a VM you could probably write to a text file on a USB,gdrive, or something like pastebin http://pastebin.com/