# Copy and paste from command line using Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

This post was handy

[Copy from guest Ubuntu terminal in virual machine to Microsoft Word on host windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421437/copy-from-guest-ubuntu-terminal-in-virual-machine-to-microsoft-word-on-host-wind)

but, whilst I've set the Copy / Paste settings, and got keyboard access to the Ubuntu command line, if I drag my mouse on the command line I can't select anything.

Is there a way to select the text?

Comment: This answer may be useful: [shortcuts to select text in terminal](http://askubuntu.com/a/55163/602680)

Comment: Is that a desktop or server version of the Ubuntu? If it's a server then I would recommend you to use putty and then you can copy paste text from that VM like it's  running a new window on your windows